# Weird syntax (Python/Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I stumpled upon this piece of code

`data.iloc[:, 2:][data.iloc[:, 2:] >= 4].count()`

Can anyone explain what `data.iloc[:, 2:] >= 4` does inside the brackets?

I know the part `data.iloc[:, 2:]`means "take all rows and all the columns after the second column", but I don't understand what `data.iloc[:, 2:] >= 4` inside the brackets does.

Comment: lookup *pandas boolean indexing*

Comment: @Ma0 No, that's masking, not boolean indexing, although it's very similar.

Comment: *Pandas is not Python*. It has its specific syntax. It has to be syntactically correct at Python level, but is *uncommon*. Not speaking of the `==` operator not returning a boolean...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's masking:

```
mask = data.iloc[:, 2:] >= 4
```

returns a boolean dataframe with the same index/columns with `data.iloc[:,2:]`. Now

```
df[mask]
```

replaces cells where `mask==False` with `np.NaN`. So

```
df[mask].count()
```

basically counts where `mask==True` column-wise.

TLDR, that line is overkilled, and equivalent to:

```
data[:, 2:].ge(4).sum()
```